# How to clear VS code terminal using python code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am taking input from user in python code. and as per user's provided input I want to clear previous outputs in terminal.

so is there any function? So I can put it in my code.

I searched on internet but it showing me Shortcut keys from keyboard but I want to clear terminal with help of code.(not want to type terminal )

Comment: Do you know how to run a command in the terminal using Python? Why not just run "clear"?

Comment: import `os` and run `os.system('clear')`

Answer (score 1):

The commands will be slightly different depending on if you're running Python in Windows or Linux/Mac (or a Unix like terminal while in Windows)

- In Windows terminals, the command to clear the screen is `cls`.
- In Max/Linux/Unix, the command is `clear`.
- Windows Powershell appears to
  except either `cls` or `clear`.

To call the appropriate command from within a script, you need to import the `os` module and call `os.system(cmd)`.  This will return a value of 0 for success, so if you are testing it in the terminal directly you may see an extra 0 get displayed on the screen if you don't put the return value into a variable.

Here's some code to call the correct function based on your os.  os.name will return 'nt' for Windows or 'posix' for Mac/Linux

```
import os

# define our clear function
def clear():
    # for Windows
    if os.name == 'nt':
        _ = os.system('cls')

    # Mac or Linux (aka posix)
    else:
        _ = os.system('clear')
```

Calling the clear() function in your script should clear the terminal as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the terminal with:

```
print('\x1b[H\x1b[2J', end='')
```

...or...

```
from sys import stdout
stdout.write('\x1b[H\x1b[2J')
```

...which is probably more efficient than os.system(...)

The string is actually 2 CSI sequences. The first moves the cursor to the screen origin (1, 1). The second sequence is the clear screen directive

Comment: This only works for terminals compatible with ANSI escape codes, mainly Linux and macOS. The new Windows Terminal app is compatible, as well as the enhanced console host from a certain (1909 I think?) build of Windows 10, and Windows 11. Previous versions of Windows are not compatible with this approach as they do not support the ANSI escapes.

Comment: @MarcSances As there is nothing in the question about the runtime environment I made an assumption that OP is using a proper Operating System